# dynamically selecting all variables with the same prefix in php

Tags: php

I have a form and there is a button to append another set of input boxes if you wish to add more information. Everytime it adds a new set of boxes all the input boxes get a unqiue number added on for that set of input boxes.

**Example:**

If you have three sets of input boxes it would look like this:

`name, age, gender, dob`

`name1, age1, gender1, dob1`

`name2, age2, gender2, dob2`

However, when I send this information over to my php file I extract the information from the array so each one is a variable. So, name would be `$name` and name1 would be `$name1` and so on. But my question is how can I sanitize and validate all the names at once and all the ages at once etc..

The reason I am asking is because I have googled this alot and I can't find an answer on how to do this.

Comment: Use `name[]` as the name attribute, etc. then iterate through that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create sets as given in sample below:

For first set:

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" id="name1" />
<input type="text" name="gender[]" id="gender1" />
<input type="text" name="age[]" id="age1" />
<input type="text" name="dob[]" id="dob1" />
```

For second set:

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" id="name2" />
<input type="text" name="gender[]" id="gender2" />
<input type="text" name="age[]" id="age2" />
<input type="text" name="dob[]" id="dob2" />
```

and set all the further sets accordingly.

Now, to get posted data you can use

```
<?php
echo "<pre>".print_r($_POST, true)."</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use something like this for each entity:

```
<input type="text" name="age[]" id="age1" />
```

Here, id should be in incremental order with JavaScript or jQuery and name should be same which will give you an array for all the attributes in `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST`

Print `$_REQUEST` and you will come to know how exactly you can get all the data.

Answer (score 0):

You are already getting the array for the name, age, etc.

To sanitize use `array_map()` function in php. It will sanitize the array.

**EXAMPLE**

```
$result = array_map("stripslashes", $result);
```

Here `$result` is an array